# Gradle "cannot find Tools.jar" on linux

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, gradle, java-home

I am trying to build a java project using gradle on linux.

When I try to build I get the error.

"Cannot find tools.jar"

I suspect something is wrong with my JAVA_HOME variable...

I have set my etc/environment file as follows....

```
PATH=\"/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
export JAVA_HOME
```

Is this correct??

Comment: Well, open up that openjdk folder and go find the tools.jar

Comment: I really wish I could but I have no clue how to use the linux "find" command...

Comment: Based on a manual GUI search of the folders, tools.jar does not exist

Comment: `find <path> -name <file>` not too hard to remember

Answer (score 0):

My problem was an incomplete  or out of date install of open jdk. Even though the folder was there with contents, some were missing.

I had to run through the steps here again....

http://openjdk.java.net/install/